# Show that $G\to\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, $g\mapsto (x\mapsto gxg^{-1})$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $g\in G$. Prove that the function $G \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ defined by $g \mapsto \gamma_g$ is a homomorphism.

We know from a previous proof:
Prove that the function $\gamma_g\colon G \rightarrow G$ defined by $(\forall a\in G)(\gamma_g(a)=g ag^{-1})$ is an automorphism of $G$.

The automorphisms $\gamma_g$ are called 'inner' automorphisms.

Comment: The previous proof being [posted 5 minutes ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364864/inner-automorphisms-with-groups), showing a similar level of effort. This question suffers from the same mistken definition of inner automorphism (should be $gag^{-1}$)

Comment: What is the precise spelled-out meaning of "this map is a homomorphism"? At which step is it possible to fail to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We denote the function by
$$\Phi : G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G),\quad g\mapsto \gamma_g.$$
Now for all $g,h,x\in G$, 
$$
\Phi(gh)(x) = \gamma_{gh}(x) = (gh)x(gh)^{-1} = ghxg^{-1}h^{-1} = g(hxh^{-1})g^{-1} = g\Phi(h)(x)g^{-1} = \Phi(g)(\Phi(h)(x)) = (\Phi(g)\circ \Phi(h))(x).
$$
and hence
$$\Phi(gh) = \Phi(g)\circ\Phi(h).$$
So $\Phi$ is an homomorphism.